# In Makefile, how to filter out files under directories who's name match wildcard pattern?

Tags: makefile

Given a previously defined variable `$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)`, how can I remove every file that's under directory `.AppleDouble`. Note that there can be multiple `.AppleDouble` directories in various location in source tree.

I tried:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := $(filter-out %.AppleDouble%, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
```

which doesn't seem work.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately `filter-out`, etc. only support one wildcard marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(foreach f,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES),$(if $(findstring .AppleDouble,$f),,$f))
```

For directories that are **exactly** `.AppleDouble` I think you want this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(foreach f,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES),$(if $(filter .AppleDouble,$(subst /, ,$f)),,$f))
```

`findstring` is unfortunately indiscriminate in its matching. It doesn't care about word boundaries or anything.